# Firefox problem at showing some characters - ubuntu 14.10

Tags: xorg, firefox, radeon, gpu-driver

My problem is what the title says. I show an image to illustrate:

[image]

Some characters are not displayed and instead that square with random pixels appears.
It can happen in any character, sometimes can happen with the letter 'm', and at other moment with the '@', it changes. In the example image it's happening with the 'o', but at other times is another char.
The only addons I have are adblock plus and xmarks.

In chromium that doesn't happen, text is displayed correctly.

Comment: I confirm the above - I had an identical problem and it disappeared after choosing the proprietary video card driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in question

> The problem was gone when I choose to use the proprietary video card drivers instead of the x.org open source ones. I chose the proprietary one in the Alternative Drivers tab
>   The video card is a r7-240.